# Maven enforcer dependencyConvergence ONLY where a local solution is not included?

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I've had to disable the `dependencyConvergence` rule as it encourages millions of `<excludes>` which must be forever maintained once present. What I've come to want is this rule to only highlight where the lack of convergence is *uncontrolled*; Where no explicit version is given by the current project (either through `<dependencies>` or `<dependencyManagement>`).

Is that possible?

#1 `d` is possibly unaware that commons-lang3 is coming from two different transitive deps with clashing versions. Enforcer should flag this.

```
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0 paths to dependency are:
+-com.example:d:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.example:c:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-com.example:b:1.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0
and
+-com.example:d:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.example:e:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1
```

#2 `d` has explicitly included 3.1. Do not flag this. Do not insist `<exclusions>` are put it in place stating what we *don't* want because we have stated clearly what the version *do* want.

```
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0 paths to dependency are:
+-com.example:d:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.example:c:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-com.example:b:1.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0
and
+-com.example:d:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1
```

#3 More subtly, I consider `c` to have resolved any clash *with its descendents*. This should not be flagged. After all, if this same check is  run from `c` then it is scenario #2. Hence #2 is the simple case #3.

```
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0 paths to dependency are:
+-com.example:d:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.example:c:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-com.example:b:1.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0
and
+-com.example:d:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.example:c:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1
```

UPDATE:
#2 works with `<depdendencyManagement>` only. A significant side-problem is that `<depdendencyManagement>` [doesn't work transitively (MNG-5761)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5761) so any nested resolution gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the version into `<dependencyManagement>`.

Then the enforcer rule is happy and will not throw convergence errors.

BTW: You rarely need exclusions for managing dependencies, just `<dependencyManagement>`.

Comment: I swear this isn't working. Will recheck before doing something more with this SO ...

Comment: I have done this a dozen times or more. You only need to make sure that you don't add a version for the same dependency in `<dependencyManagement>` and `<dependencies>`.

Comment: Ok `<dM>` _does_ work but `<d>` alone doesn't - that's unintuitive. I think my problem is MNG-5761 Dependency management is not transitive.  This problem keeps coming back on further downstream modules unless they, too, have a local `<dM>` version for this... I see what all those <excludes> are for now - at least they are transitive

Comment: I gather the dependencyManagement in so-called BOMs and use them in dependencyManagement with scope import.

Comment: That BOM would work but involves changes to multiple teams' projects :( Seems my issue is actually not with enforcer over-reporting but with MNG-5671 screwing up the dependencies